# Create Custom POST form without grid and model in magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, backend, forms, adminform

I need a custom post form in Magento back-end where I can select some fields and post form , on its post action I need to download a csv depending on form fields.

This post form has dependable fields which may vary according to previous selection.

I have checked many question where I found creating grids based on some data-provider with UI-component. In my case I don't need to create some new table or grid to display data.

I'm open for both ways UI-component and block way.

Answer (score 0):

You need form markup, page layout and controller

In the following extension I have a form which you can use to upload a file. So opposite of what you want but similar enough to give you an idea on what needs to happen

Form

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CsvUpload/blob/master/view/adminhtml/templates/index/submit.phtml

Layout xml

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CsvUpload/blob/master/view/adminhtml/layout/xigen_csvupload_index_submit.xml

Controller form submits to

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CsvUpload/blob/master/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Process.php

Menu

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CsvUpload/blob/63b05350b7c06f4acb7d22b6f088b05f99bb7695/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml#L5

Route

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CsvUpload/blob/63b05350b7c06f4acb7d22b6f088b05f99bb7695/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml#L4